# Regular link with padding unresponsive in mobile browsers

Tags: css, button, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have a Twitter Bootstrap based Website with some strange issues on regular old link buttons (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RK3RC/)

#### HTML

```
<a class="button" href="http://jsfiddle.net/">Click Me</a>
```

#### CSS

```
.button {
    background-color: #bc4b4e;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 14px 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    left: 220px;
    top: 20px;
    visibility: visible;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #d35559;
}
```

The buttons work absolutely fine and as expected in desktop browsers, but are not responsive in mobile browsers (touch devices). If you click them through touch, nothing happens - the buttons are non-responsive. However, interestingly, if the link is to an anchor tag on the *same* page, it will work (just not to an outside page).

Any thoughts/suggestions? I've scoured the Web but haven't found people with the exact same issue, which is a bit odd in itself.

Comment: `left: 220px;` will cause you no end of problems in this instance when it comes to responsiveness. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You link opens for me on iPhone 5 with iOS 6 using both Chrome and Safari. I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.

Comment: The fiddle opens for me on a gs3 in dolphin.

Comment: @Vector - the absolute positioning values are actually generated by JS and scales to the screen, so the positioning itself is fine.

Comment: @MichaelFreake Worked for me too (also iPhone5 with iOS6).

Comment: @MichaelFreake very strange, in mobile chrome (Android ice scream sandwich) nothing happens when you touch the button... yet if the link is to an anchor on the same page, it works fine

Comment: @SamSlover Worked fine in Chrome on iOS6, iPhone5.

Comment: Works fine for me (in that it opens JS Fiddle in the 'result' panel when the button is clicked) in Chrome, on Android 4.2, in both Nexus 4 and Nexus 7.

Comment: very, very odd. im not sure what is going on with my device.. trying some things. will report back. thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out.

It was actually because there was a JQuery-based slider, on a different part of the page, that had a touchenabled setting (which allows the user to go through the slider by swiping). This was affecting the button's response to touch. Once that touch setting was turned off, the buttons everywhere respond as normal.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions. You guys rock.